# Unable to access Go service running in WSL2 from external IP, but can access via localhost

Tags: windows, go, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a Go service within WSL2 on my Windows desktop. The service seems to start up fine, initializing Kafka producers and connecting to Neo4j without any issues. I'm trying to access this service from a Postman client running on my MacBook, which is on the same network.

Details:

The service runs on port 8082 within WSL2.
I can access the service via localhost:8082/newpost from the Windows host machine, and I get a "bad request" response (which is expected).
However, when I try accessing via the external IP (192.168.1.83:8082/newpost), I get a timeout.
I have added a rule in the Windows Firewall for port 8082.

Steps tried:

Checked if the port is in use. It isn't.
Used the netsh command to create a port forwarding rule. No success.
Checked accessing the service via the Windows host machine using curl, and it couldn't connect.
Switched ports, but the issue persists.
Verified that client isolation isn't the problem as I can communicate with other devices on the same network.
Tried binding the Go app to the Windows host IP (192.168.1.83), but it gives an error: bind: cannot assign requested address.

From my code:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil)
```

Network Configuration:

WSL2 IP: 172.24.10.153

Windows Host IP: 192.168.1.83

Comment: Notice the IP address of your WSL2 VM: 172.24.10.153. So I don't understand why you would try to access your HTTP server at 192.168.1.83:8082.